# how to animate height of a div back-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to show some part of a div and animate it to 100% when the div is clicked.
and I want to animate it back to the initial height of the div if it's clicked again. 
this is what i have so far,but it doesn't work. can anyone help?

```
#mydiv {
    height:150px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mydiv").click(function(){
            $(this).animate({height: '100%'}, 300);
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({height: '150px'}, 300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried toggle function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click()` doesn't accept two function arguments, previously there was a `toggle()` function that performed how you need it but it has now been deprecated and removed from jQuery.

Since your use case is pretty simple, I believe something like this would be enough:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({
        height: $this.height() == 150 ? '100%' : 150
    }, 300);
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/fBSXK/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: '100%'}, 300);
        };
        function() {
            $(this).animate({height: 150}, 300);
        });
});
```

Comment: `toggle()` has been deprecated since version 1.8 and was removed from jquery in version 1.9

Comment: You are correct.  However, I used the Migrate Plugin allowing this format to work.  I do recommend your solution though, as this will become the norm in the near future.  Thanks.